# How to add MUI tooltip component to React-tiptap when characters limit has reached

Tags: reactjs, tiptap

I'm using React tiptap Wysiwyg. I need to validate character limit and show the user a tooltip above the caret that warns him of that limitation.I'm using `CharacterCount` extension to validate char count which works well, also for caret styling. how do I inject a tooltip to that position? I was trying to inject a custom node to this position and then querying the element and rendering MUI tooltip but it was kinda buggy...

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you tried?